# apache_setenv() not found in apache server

Tags: php, apache

I am running a whm/cpanel server and trying to call apache_setenv() to disable gzip buffering. But PHP tells me that this function does not exist. It's my understanding that it's part of mod_php and should be present. Is there another module I need to install?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that ... php 5.4.35 and apache 2.2.29

Comment: It appears this function is not available when running php as a CGI interpreter vs a module. But AFAIK it's set up as a module. I'm trying to figure out how to confirm this.